# What is a "two-dimensional space of vectors"?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/31440/174131) to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/31436/174131) it is stated that given $n+2$ vectors $(v_1,...,v_n,v_{n+1},v_{n+2})\in \mathbb{R}^n$:

> There is at least a two-dimensional space
> of vectors $(a_1,\ldots,a_{n+2})$ such that
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+2} a_i v_i=0.$$

I'm not sure what this means.  What is a "two-dimensional space of vectors"?  The thing in the parenthesis that follows the utterance, $(a_1,\ldots,a_{n+2})$, looks like a sequence of $n+2$ real numbers.  How is that a "two-dimensional space of vectors" (whatever that means) ?

(Does it mean a vector space that is spanned by a basis consisting of two vectors?  If so how do the $n+2$ real numbers define a vector space?)

Comment: The summation calls for $v_{n+1}$ and $v_{n+2}$. What does this mean?

Comment: I guess it means the set of linear relations between the $n+2$ vectors is a subspace of $\mathbf R^{n+2}$ of dimension at least $2$. What's intriguing me is the discrepancy between the number of vectors in the linear relation and the number of given vectors.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Updated to be more correct.

Comment: It means that the set of vectors of the form $(a_1, \ldots, a_{n+2})$ satisfying the given linear dependence condition is a vector space with dimension at least two. I agree that the wording isn't very clear.

Comment: @Bernard: Do you mean the linear combinations of the $v_i$s ?

Comment: $(a_1,\dots,a_{n+2})$ is a single vector in ${\bf R}^{n+2}$. What's being said (I think) is that there is a subspace $W$ of ${\bf R}^{n+2}$ such that the dimension of $W$ is two, and every element $(a_1,\dots,a_{n+2})$ of $W$ satisfies the given equation. But the question @Ted raises needs attention.

Comment: Yes, they're usually called the vector space of relations between the vectors (or the module of relations if  you work over a ring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is the easiest way for you to see it. Let $M$ be the $n\times (n+2)$ matrix whose columns are the vectors $v_i$ (say, written in terms of the standard basis). The matrix $M$ has rank at most $n$. Therefore, the subspace of vectors $X$ so that $MX=0$ (the kernel or nullspace) has dimension at least $(n+2)-n=2$ (nullity-rank theorem). These vectors $X$ are the the vectors $(a_1,\dots,a_{n+2})$ to which the original author is referring.

Comment: That matrix has $n+2$ columns, but (as you pointed out) we only have $n$ vectors $v_i$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: No, I think we have $n+2$ vectors $v_i$, each are an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so we could concatenate them to form an n by $n+2$ matrix.

Comment: @Gerry He revised before I wrote that.

Comment: OK, Ted. It was still $n$ when I was looking at it.

Comment: Sorry, yeah I didnt transcribe it right in the first revision.  My bad.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that if all the $a$'s are $0$, you get a valid solution.
Also, if a set of $a$'s are a solution, then if you multiply by a constant $k$, the $ka$'s also form a solution.  Likewise, the sets of $a$'s satisfy the other requirements for a vector space.

It so happens that you can find exactly two linearly independent solutions, and all other solutions are linear combinations of those.  The space of solutions is 2 dimensional.  We are talking about space where the $a$'s are the components, not the $v$'s.

For example, you might have a solution of the form $(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2)$ and another of the form $(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0)$ and so all linear combinations of those would be the space of solutions, a subspace of the (in my example) $8$ dimensional space of all possible sets of coefficients $a$'s.

I admit I found it weird when I first got exposed to the idea of the solutions of a differential equation forming a vector space.  For example $y" + y = 0$ has two linearly independent solutions, namely $y_1 = \sin x$ and $y_2 = \cos x$, and so anything like $5y_1 - 3y_2$ is also a solution.  But they follow all the rules of a vector space, so they form one!